# How can I get some data from a video YouTube? (Python)

Tags: python, youtube, analytics

I want to know how can I get some data from a video Youtube like views, thumbnails or coments it has. I have been looking for in the Google's API but I can't understand it.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried, what have you not understood? See [mcve] & [ask].

Comment: [this might help you](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2014/09/mining-youtube-python-social-media-analysis/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach would be using urllib2 and getting the HTML code from the page and then filtering it.

```
import urllib2
source = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDjeBNv6ip0'
response = urllib2.urlopen(source)
html = response.read() #Done, you have the whole HTML file in a gigantic string.
```

After that all you have to do is to filter it as you would do to a string.

Getting the **number of views** for instance:

```
wordBreak = ['<','>']  
html = list(html)
i = 0
while i < len(html):
    if html[i] in wordBreak:
        html[i] = ' '
    i += 1

#The block above is just to make the html.split() easier.

html = ''.join(html)
html = html.split()
dataSwitch = False
numOfViews = ''
for element in html:
    if element == '/div':
        dataSwitch = False
    if dataSwitch:
        numOfViews += str(element)
    if element == 'class="watch-view-count"':
        dataSwitch = True

print (numOfViews)
>>> 45.608.212 views
```

This was a simple example of getting the number of views but you can do that to everything on the page, including number of comments, likes, the content of the comment itself, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the the part you are looking for ([source](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/python)):

```
def get_video_localization(youtube, video_id, language):
    results = youtube.videos().list(
    part="snippet",
    id=video_id,
    hl=language
    ).execute()

    localized = results["items"][0]["snippet"]["localized"]
```

`localized` will now contain title, description, etc.